# Clear all textbox in a windows form except special ones

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using following code to clear all text boxes in a form.

```
protected static IEnumerable<Control> GetAllChildren(Control root)
        {
            var stack = new Stack<Control>();
            stack.Push(root);
            while (stack.Any())
            {
                var next = stack.Pop();
                foreach (Control child in next.Controls)
                    stack.Push(child);
                yield return next;
            }
        }

internal static void ResetTextBoxes(Control root, string resetWith = "", params TextBox[] except)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (TextBox txt in GetAllChildren(root).OfType<TextBox>())
                {
                    foreach (TextBox txtException in except)
                    {
                        if (txtException.Name != txt.Name)
                        {
                            txt.Text = resetWith == "" ? string.Empty : resetWith;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
        }
```

I tried to separate some special text boxes those I don't want to be cleared by using params, but still it clears all the boxes. Need help, please.

Comment: Unrelated to your question: What is the purpose of your `try-catch` block? Consider removing it.

Comment: @sstan actually this is standard practice for the group i'm working on, nothing else.

Comment: I mention it because it's not good practice to systematically add try-catches that only re-raise the exception, doing nothing else. It adds unnecessary overhead.  Additionally, even if you do need to do it, then use `throw;` instead of `throw ex;` to reraise the exception, otherwise you lose the original (and most important) exception stack trace.

Comment: @sstan Great advice!! Thank you so much. I'll discuss with my group about this ASAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shorter version of `GetAllChildren`:

```
protected static IEnumerable<Control> GetAllChildren(Control root) {
  return new Control[] { root }
    .Concat(root.Controls
      .OfType<Control>()
      .SelectMany(item => GetAllChildren(item)));
}
```

And shorter Linq:

```
var source = GetAllChildren(root)
  .OfType<TextBox>()
  .Where(ctrl => !except.Contains(ctrl));

foreach (var textBox in source)
  textBox.Text = resetWith;
```

The *problem* with your current implmentation is in the inner loop:

```
foreach (TextBox txtException in except)
  if (txtException.Name != txt.Name)
    txt.Text = resetWith == "" ? string.Empty : resetWith;
```

if you have at least *two* exceptions with *different* names that condition

```
 txtException.Name != txt.Name
```

will be *inevitably satisfied* (any `txt.Name` either *not equal* 1st exception or 2nd one)

Comment: Excellent solution... Nice and clean code. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening since you are testing all the elements the first collection against all the elements of the second collection, so even if a textbox exists in the `except` array, it's name will not match the other textboxes there.
Use Linq's `Any` extension method instead:

```
internal static void ResetTextBoxes(Control root, string resetWith = "", params TextBox[] except)
{
    foreach (TextBox txt in GetAllChildren(root).OfType<TextBox>())
    {
        if(!except.Any(t => t.Name == txt.Name))
            {
                txt.Text = resetWith == "" ? string.Empty : resetWith;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function I use:

```
    public void ClearAllFields(Control con)
    {
        foreach (Control c in con.Controls)
        {
            if (c is TextBox && c != null)
            {
                if (c.Name != "specialtxtbox1name" && c.Name != "specialtxtbox2name" && c.Name != "nameoftextbox") // just put in the name of special textBoxes between double quotes
                    c.Text = "";
            }
            else
            {
                ClearAllFields(c);
            }
        }

    }
```

Simply call the function wherever needed

Example:

```
    private void InsertDatathenClearForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
               //Code
               //.
               //.
                File.Create(filepath);
                MessageBox.Show("All Textboxes Data saved successfully");
               //Clear fxn
                ClearAllFields(this);
      }
```

.
.

}